# How many special/normal weapons can be upgraded to max in first playthrough in Elden ring?

Tags: elden-ring

Currently in my first play-through. Nightrider Glaive (+17) and Bloodhound's Fang (+9) -at present- are my primary weapons of choice. Just got on Altus plateau and I am getting my hands on several weapons that I like to use. Are resources limited to only one special/normal weapon to the max?

Comment: I'm not sure how many, but you can max multiple weapons on your playthrough

Comment: Note that you can find bell bearings that enables npcs to sell you every kind of smithing stones and somber smithing stones, except for the ancient dragon ones required for the final level of a weapon. Which means this question is basically "how many ancient dragon smithing stones are there in the game". : I don't know the answer, but if you play new game+ then they'll become available again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each play through you can upgrade [8 special](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Somber+Ancient+Dragon+Smithing+Stone) and [13 normal](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Ancient+Dragon+Smithing+Stone) weapon to the maximum level (level 10 for special and 25 for normal).

Though you can eventually upgrade to the previous level (level 9 for special and 24 for normal) any number of weapon in each play-through. As you can later buy upgrades materials.